# In JIRA Agile, when I click a quickfilter I want other quickfilters to be unclicked, how can I do this?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

In JIRA, you can create quick filters so you can easily find your issues based on some custom filterings. For example, I have the following quick filters:

- Bugs
- My issues
- Coworker's issues
- Recently created

When I click each one of them I want all others be become deselected. How can I do this? Right now they all stay selected when I click around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: **you can't**. They are just designed as a toggle buttons.

But... if you are really depressed to do that you can create JIRA plugin which will inject some JavaScript to do that for you ;)